# Conditional expectation and computation of double integrals

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, multiple-integral

I consider $X,Y$ two independent uniform on $[0,1]$ and $M=\min(X,Y)$.

I want to compute $\mathbb{E}(X^{2} | M]$ using the orthogonality relation that caracterizes the conditionnal expectation. For this I consider $Z$ a random variable $\sigma(M)$ measurable, we know it is a function of $M$ such that $Z = \psi(M)$. Thus we are seeking $\phi(M)$ satisfying for all $\psi$ measurable function the following relation

$$
\mathbb{E}(\psi(M)(X^{2} - \phi(M)) = 0
$$

By the transfert theorem and independence (and Fubini) we get

$$
\int_{\Omega} \psi(M)(X^{2} - \phi(M))d\mathbb{P} = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \psi(m)(X^{2} - \phi(m))d\mathbb{P}_1 d\mathbb{P}_2 = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\psi(m)(x^{2} - \phi(m))dxdy = 0
$$

where $m=\min(x,y)$. From there we can split the integral on $x$ as follows to get rid of the minimum

$$
\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{y}\psi(x)(x^{2} - \phi(x))dx + \int_{y}^{1}\psi(y)(x^{2} - \phi(y))dx \right)dy = \int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{y}\psi(x)(x^{2} - \phi(x))dx +\psi(y) \left(\frac{1+y^3}{3} - (1-y)\phi(y)\right) \right)dy = 0 
$$

I wanted to simply the two inner integral in order to have a unique expression under one integral but I am stuck for the first integral. I think my cutting is not good but I don't see which one applied, do you have any ideas?

I **insist** on this particular method please

Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You approach is good. What you need is to **convert the double integral** (or an expectation of two random variables) **to a single integral** (or an expectation of one random variable). Here is what I suggest:

- Solution 1: based on your idea
- Solution 2: the generic solution (longer than solution 1) for these kind of problems

### Solution 1:

$$\begin{align}
0 &= \mathbb{E}(\psi(M)(X^{2} - \phi(M))  \\
 &= \mathbb{E}(\psi(M)(X^{2} - \phi(M)  \mathbf{1}_{\{X\ge Y  \}})+\mathbb{E}(\psi(M)(X^{2} - \phi(M)  \mathbf{1}_{\{X\le Y  \}})  \\
 &= \mathbb{E}(\psi(Y)(X^{2} - \phi(Y))  \mathbf{1}_{\{X\ge Y  \}})+\mathbb{E}(\psi(X)(X^{2} - \phi(X))  \mathbf{1}_{\{X\le Y  \}})  \\
&= \mathbb{E}(\psi(Y)X^{2}\mathbf{1}_{\{X\ge Y  \}}) -\mathbb{E}(\psi(Y)\phi(Y)  \mathbf{1}_{\{X\ge Y  \}})  +\mathbb{E}(\psi(X)X^{2}  \mathbf{1}_{\{X\le Y  \}})-\mathbb{E}(\psi(X) \phi(X)  \mathbf{1}_{\{X\le Y  \}})  \\
\end{align}$$

We have:

$$\begin{align}
\text{Term } 1 &= \mathbb{E}(\psi(Y)X^{2}\mathbf{1}_{\{X\ge Y  \}}) = \mathbb{E}\left(\psi(Y) \int_Y^1x^2dx\right) =\mathbb{E}\left(\psi(Y)\frac{1-Y^3}{3}\right)\\
\text{Term } 2 &= \mathbb{E}\left(\psi(Y)\phi(Y)   \int_X^1 dx\right) =  \mathbb{E}\left(\psi(Y)\phi(Y)   (1-Y)\right)\\
\text{Term } 3 &= \mathbb{E}(\psi(X)X^{2}  \int_X^1dy) = \mathbb{E}(\psi(X)X^{2}  (1-X))\\
\text{Term } 4 &= \mathbb{E}(\psi(X) \phi(X)  \mathbf{1}_{\{X\le Y  \}})=\mathbb{E}(\psi(X) \phi(X)  \int_X^1dy)=\mathbb{E}(\psi(X) \phi(X)  (1-X))
\end{align}$$

Then for **all** function  $\psi$, we have

$$\begin{align}
0 &= \mathbb{E}\left(\psi(Y)\frac{1-Y^3}{3}\right)-\mathbb{E}\left(\psi(Y)\phi(Y)   (1-Y)\right)+\mathbb{E}(\psi(X)X^{2}  (1-X))-\mathbb{E}(\psi(X) \phi(X)  (1-X))\\
&=\mathbb{E} \left( \psi(X)\frac{1-X^3}{3}  - \psi(X)\phi(X)   (1-X) + \psi(X)X^{2}  (1-X) -\psi(X) \phi(X)  (1-X) \right)\\
&=\mathbb{E} \left( \psi(X)  \left(  \frac{1-X^3}{3}  - \phi(X)   (1-X) + X^{2}  (1-X) - \phi(X)  (1-X) \right)\right)  \\
&= \int_0^1 \psi(x) \color{red}{ \left(  \frac{1-x^3}{3}  - \phi(x)   (1-x) + x^{2}  (1-x) - \phi(x)  (1-x) \right)}dx \tag{1}
\end{align}$$

As $(1)$ holds true for **all** function $\psi$, we must have for all $x \in [0,1]$
$$\begin{align}
 &\frac{1-x^3}{3}  - \phi(x)   (1-x) + x^{2}  (1-x) - \phi(x)  (1-x) = 0\\
&\implies 2(1-x) \phi(x) =  \frac{1-x^3}{3}  + x^2(1-x) \\
&\implies  \color{red}{\phi(x) =  \frac{1+x+4x^2}{6}}\end{align}$$

### Solution 2:

From the result of the [conditional continuous distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution#Conditional_continuous_distributions), we have
$$f_{X|M}(x|m) =\frac{f_{X,M}(x,m)}{f_M(m)}$$
where

- $f_{X|M}(x|m)$: the conditional density function of $X$ given $M$
- $f_{X,M}(x,m)$: the joint density function of $X$ and $M$
- $f_M(m)$: the density function of $M$

---

The density function $f_M(m)$ can be easily calculated:

$$f_M(m) = \frac{\partial}{\partial m}\mathbb{P}(M\le m)= \frac{\partial}{\partial m}\left(1-  \mathbb{P}(M\ge m) \right) =\frac{\partial}{\partial m}\left(1-  (1-m)^2 \right) =2(1-m)$$

And we find the joint density function $f_{X,M}(x,m)$ as follows: for **any** function $g(X,M)$, we have
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(g(X,M)) &=  \mathbb{E}(g(X,M)  \mathbf{1}_{\{X\ge Y  \}})+\mathbb{E}(g(X,M)  \mathbf{1}_{\{X\le Y  \}})\\
&=\mathbb{E}(g(X,Y)  \mathbf{1}_{\{X\ge Y  \}})+\mathbb{E}(g(X,X)  \mathbf{1}_{\{X\le Y  \}})\\
&= \iint_{\{(x,y=\in [0,1]^2  \}} g(x,y)\mathbf{1}_{\{x\ge y  \}}dxdy + \int_{\{(x\in [0,1]  \}}g(x,x)\left( \int_x^1 dy \right) dx\\
&= \iint_{\{(x,y=\in [0,1]^2  \}} g(x,y)\mathbf{1}_{\{x\ge y  \}}dxdy + \int_{\{(x\in [0,1]  \}}g(x,x)(1-x) dx\\
&= \iint_{\{(x,y=\in [0,1]^2  \}} g(x,y)\mathbf{1}_{\{x\ge y  \}}dxdy + \iint_{\{(x,y=\in [0,1]^2  \}}g(x,\color{red}{y})(1-x)\color{red}{\mathbf{1}_{\{x= y  \}}}  dx\\
&=\iint_{\{(x,y=\in [0,1]^2  \}} g(x,y) \underbrace{\left(  \mathbf{1}_{\{x\ge y  \}} + (1-x)\mathbf{1}_{\{x= y  \}} \right)}_{ = f_{X,M}(x,y)}dxdy
\end{align}$$
because $\mathbb{E}(g(X,M))$ is also equal to $\iint_{\{(x,y=\in [0,1]^2  \}} g(x,y) f_{X,M}(x,y) dxdy$ for all function $g(x,y)$.

---

Then
$$\color{red}{f_{X|M}(x|m) =\frac{ \mathbf{1}_{\{x\ge m  \}} + (1-x)\mathbf{1}_{\{x= m \}}}{2(1-m)}} \tag{1}$$
(the function $\mathbf{1}_{\{x=m \}}$ is the function Dirac, sometimes it is denoted by $\delta_{\{x=m \}}$)

---

Now, we compute $\mathbb{E}(X^2|M)$ by using $(1)$:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(X^2|M) &= \int_0^1 x^2 f_{X|M}(x|M)dx \\
&= \int_0^1 x^2 \cdot \frac{ \mathbf{1}_{\{x\ge M  \}} + (1-x)\mathbf{1}_{\{x=M \}}}{2(1-M)}   dx \\
&=\frac{1}{2(1-M)} \left(\int_M^1 x^2 dx +  M^2(1-M) \right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2(1-M)} \left(\frac{1}{3}(1-M^3) dx +  M^2(1-M) \right)\\
&= \frac{1+M+4M^2}{6} 
\end{align}$$

**Remark:** this technique can solved easily the kind of problems (for example: compute $\mathbb{E}(X^n|\min\{X,Y \})$, $\mathbb{E}(\max\{X,Y \}|\min\{X,Y \})$,...)

Comment: Thank you a lot for this answer really ! I did not think about adding indicator function to facilitate the computation. However in the expectation how do you go from $\mathbb{E}(\psi(Y)X^{2}1_{X\geq Y})= \mathbb{E}(\psi(Y)\int_{Y}^{1}x^2dx))$ (I wrote the term 1 but I adress this concern for all term in fact) ? If you use independence I see why we can compute the expectation of $X^2$ but not why for the indicator function since $Y$ is in the indicator function so it breaks up the possibility to have the product $\mathbb{E}(\psi(Y))\mathbb{E}(X^{2}1_{X\geq Y})$ ?

Comment: @coboy In fact, I used here the conditional expectation : $$\mathbb{E}(\psi(Y)X^2 \mathbf{1}_{\{X \ge Y\}}) =\mathbb{E}(\psi(Y)\color{red}{\mathbb{E}(X^2 \mathbf{1}_{\{X \ge Y   \}}|Y)}) = \mathbb{E}(\psi(Y)\color{red}{\int_Y^1x^2dx}) $$
We cannot do $\mathbb{E}(\psi(Y)X^2 \mathbf{1}_{\{X \ge Y\}}) =\mathbb{E}(\psi(Y))\color{red}{\mathbb{E}(X^2 \mathbf{1}_{\{X \ge Y   \}})}$ (because there is no equality here)

Comment: Oh yes ! Thank you a lot !

Comment: @coboy you’re welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Here is my approach. Fix $m\in [0,1].$

Set $A_m=(m\times [m,1])\cup ([m,1]\times m)$.

Then $\{M=m\}=\{(X,Y)\in A_m\}$ so the conditional denisty of $(X,Y)$ given $M=m$ namely $f_{X,Y|A_m}$ is $$f_{X,Y|A_m}(x,y)=\frac{1}{2(1-m)}\cdot 1_{A_m}(x,y)$$ The $2(1-m)$ in the denominator normalizes the area of the region in the $xyz$ plane below the $z=f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ and above $A_m$.

So, $$\mathbb{E}(X^2|M=m)=\int_{y=m}^{y=1}m^2f_{X,Y|A_m}(m,y)\mathrm{dy}+\int_{x=m}^{x=1}x^2f_{X,Y|A_m}(x,m)\mathrm{d}x=\frac{ 4m^2+m+1 }{6}$$

We get $$\mathbb{E}(X^2|M)=\frac{4M^2+M+1}{6}$$

Answer (score 2):

I did not understand the details of the question, so I did not check the correctness of the transformations below. But they provide the same value of $\psi(M)$ as Matthew H.'s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4786093/conditional-expectation-and-computation-of-double-integrals/4786276#4786276).

$$
\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{y}\psi(x)(x^{2} - \phi(x))dx + \int_{y}^{1}\psi(y)(x^{2} - \phi(y))dx \right)dy = \int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{y}\psi(x)(x^{2} - \phi(x))dx +\psi(y) \left(\frac{1\color{red}-y^3}{3} - (1-y)\phi(y)\right) \right)dy = 0.$$

$$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{y}\psi(x)(x^{2} - \phi(x))dx\right)dy=$$
$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{x}^{1} \psi(x)(x^{2} - \phi(x)) dy dx=$$
$$\int_{0}^{1} (1-x)\psi(x)(x^{2} - \phi(x))dx.$$

So

$$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{y}\psi(x)(x^{2} - \phi(x))dx +\psi(y) \left(\frac{1-y^3}{3} - (1-y)\phi(y)\right) \right)dy=$$
$$\int_{0}^{1} (1-t)\psi(t)(t^{2} - \phi(t))+\psi(t) \left(\frac{1-t^3}{3} - (1-t)\phi(t)\right)dt.$$

As I understood, this expression equals $0$ for each measurable function $\psi$.
So $$0=(1-t)(t^{2} - \phi(t))+\left(\frac{1-t^3}{3} - (1-t)\phi(t)\right)=(1-t)(t^{2} - 2\phi(t))+\frac{1-t^3}{3}.$$

When $t\ne 1$ we obtain

$$t^{2} - 2\phi(t)+\frac{1+t+t^2}{3}=0$$

$$\phi(t)=\frac{1+t+4t^2}{6}.$$